# Estou com problema quando invoco um método - JAVA

Tags: java

Estou trabalhando em um código de locadora de filmes Online, código simples para entregar a meu professor da escola cientifica e estou tendo o seguinte erro: Na hora que eu cadastro um filme e vou listar o filme aparece os filmes cadastrados e os clientes quero saber como eu consigo deixar para no meu método filme só aparecer os filmes e em cliente só clientes.
Segue abaixo o meu código e suas respectivas classes incluindo o método main.

Classe: Cliente

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Cliente {

    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private String rua;
    private String complemento;
    private String cidade;
    private String estado;
    private String cep;

    private int codigo;
    private int numero;
    private int dia;
    private int mes;
    private int ano;
    private int mescadastro;
    private int diacadastro;
    private int anocadastro;

    public void setDiac(int dayc) {
        diacadastro = dayc;

    }

    public void setMesc(int mc) {
        mescadastro = mc;
    }

    public void setAnoc(int yearc) {
        anocadastro = yearc;

    }

    public void setDia(int day) {
        dia = day;

    }

    public void setMes(int m) {
        mes = m;
    }

    public void setAno(int year) {
        ano = year;

    }

    public void setRua(String n) {
        rua = n;
    }

    public void setNumero(int casan) {
        numero = casan;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String com) {
        complemento = com;

    }

    public void setCidade(String city) {
        cidade = city;
    }

    public void setEstado(String state) {
        estado = state;
    }

    public void setCep(String ddd) {
        cep = ddd;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int c) {
        codigo = c;
    }

    public void setNome(String name) {
        this.nome = name;

    }

    public void setTelefone(String tel) {
        telefone = tel;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

}
```

Classe: Filme

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Filme {

    private String titulo;
    private String genero;
    private int Anodelancamento;
    private int Duracao;


private int codigo;



void setCodigo(int c){
    codigo = c;

}

int getCodigo(){

    return codigo;

}
    void setTitulo(String t) {

        titulo = t;

    }

    String getTitulo(){
        return titulo;
    }

    void setGenero(String g) {

        genero = g;

    }

    void setAnodelancamento(int an) {

        Anodelancamento = an;

    }

    void setDuracao(int d) {

        Duracao = d;

    }



}
```

Classe: ClienteDao

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ClienteDao {

    /*
     DESENVOLVIDO BY: "Igor Team"
     */

    int codc;
    int tamanhoDoVetor;
    Cliente[] clienteArray;
    Filme[] filmeArray;

    public ClienteDao(int tamanhoDoVetor) {

        this.tamanhoDoVetor = tamanhoDoVetor;
        clienteArray = new Cliente[tamanhoDoVetor];
        filmeArray = new Filme[tamanhoDoVetor];
    }

    int aux;

    public void cadastroCliente(int n) {
        // Se eu ja cadastrei n numero e quero cadastrar mais n

        aux = n + aux;

        for (int ig = 0; ig < aux; ig++) {
            if (clienteArray[ig] == null) {

                clienteArray[ig] = new Cliente();
                clienteArray[ig].setCodigo(ig);
                clienteArray[ig].setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog((ig + 1) + "º Cliente\nNome: "));
                /* clienteArray[ig].setRua(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Rua: "));
                 clienteArray[ig].setNumero(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nº: ")));
                 clienteArray[ig].setComplemento(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Complemento: "));
                 clienteArray[ig].setCidade(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cidade: "));
                 clienteArray[ig].setEstado(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Estado: "));
                 clienteArray[ig].setCep(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("CEP: "));
                 clienteArray[ig].setTelefone(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Telefone: "));

                 clienteArray[ig].setDiac(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cadastro" + "\nDia: ")));
                 clienteArray[ig].setMesc(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Mês: ")));
                 clienteArray[ig].setAnoc(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano: ")));

                 clienteArray[ig].setDia(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nascimento" + "\nDia: ")));
                 clienteArray[ig].setMes(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Mês: ")));
                 clienteArray[ig].setAno(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano: "))); */

            }

        }
    }

    public void consultarPorNome() {
        String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Nome do cliente");
        for (Cliente c : clienteArray) {
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.getNome().equals(nome)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigo: "
                            + (c.getCodigo() + 1) + "\nNome: " + c.getNome());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nenhum cliente com o nome " + nome
                + " encontrado");
    }

    public void mostrarClientes() {
        for (Cliente c : clienteArray) {
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.getCodigo() != -1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigo: " + (c.getCodigo() + 1) + "\nNome: " + c.getNome());
return;
                }
            } 

        }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nenhum cliente cadastrado");
    }

    public void apagarCliente() {
        int senhac2 = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "DIGITE SUA SENHA DE ADMINISTRADOR")));

        if (senhac2 == 12345) {
            int codigo = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Digite o código do cliente desejado: ")) - 1);
            if (procurarCliente(codigo) != true) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente inexistente!");
            } else {
                //adicionei parenteses ao pegar o código para que ele incremente
                //1 apos pegar o código do cliente
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Código: " + ((clienteArray[codigo].getCodigo()) + 1)
                        + "\nNome: " + clienteArray[codigo].getNome());
                clienteArray[codigo] = null;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Exclusão concluida com SUCESSO");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "SENHA INCORRETA DE ADMINISTRADOR");
        }
    }

    public boolean procurarCliente(int n) {

        for(int i = 0; i < clienteArray.length; i++) {
            if (clienteArray[i] != null) {
                if (clienteArray[i].getCodigo() == n) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    //FILMES
    char auxf = '0';
    int auxf2 = 0;
    int quantidadeFinal;

    public void cadastrarFilmes(int qtdfilme) {
        int senhac = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("DIGITE SUA SENHA DE ADMINISTRADOR")));
        if (senhac == 12345) {
            auxf2 = qtdfilme + auxf2;
            for (int fi = 0; fi < auxf2; fi++) {

                if (filmeArray[fi] == null) {
                    filmeArray[fi] = new Filme();
                    filmeArray[fi].setCodigo(fi);
                    filmeArray[fi].setTitulo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Titulo " + (fi + 1) + "º: "));

                    auxf = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Gênero do filme\n1-AÇÃO\n2-COMÉDIA\n3-SUSPENSE\n4-DRAMA").charAt(0);

                    switch (auxf) {
                        case '1':
                            //                 filmeArray[fi].setGenero("AÇAO");
                            //               filmeArray[fi].setAnodelancamento(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano de Lançamento: ")));
                            //    filmeArray[fi].setDuracao(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duração do filme em minutos: ")));
                            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme: " + filmeArray[fi].getTitulo() + " CADASTRADO!!!");
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            filmeArray[fi].setGenero("COMEDIA");
                            filmeArray[fi].setAnodelancamento(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano de Lançamento: ")));
                            filmeArray[fi].setDuracao(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duração do filme em minutos: ")));
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme: " + filmeArray[fi].getTitulo() + " CADASTRADO!!!");
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            filmeArray[fi].setGenero("SUSPENSE");
                            filmeArray[fi].setAnodelancamento(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano de Lançamento: ")));
                            filmeArray[fi].setDuracao(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duração do filme em minutos: ")));
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme: " + filmeArray[fi].getTitulo() + " CADASTRADO!!!");
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            filmeArray[fi].setGenero("DRAMA");
                            filmeArray[fi].setAnodelancamento(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano de Lançamento: ")));
                            filmeArray[fi].setDuracao(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duração do filme em minutos: ")));
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme: " + filmeArray[fi].getTitulo() + " CADASTRADO!!!");
                            break;
                        default:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opção inválida! ou Gênero do filme não cadastro no sistema! ");
                    }

                }
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SENHA DO ADMINISTRADOR INVALIDA");
        }
    }

    public void listaFilmes() {
        for (Filme gi : filmeArray) {
            if (gi != null) {
                if (gi.getCodigo() != -1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigo: " + (gi.getCodigo() + 1) + "\nNome: " + gi.getTitulo());
return;
                } 
            }

        }

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não existe filmes registrados!");

    }

    public void removerFilmes() {
        int senhacd = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "DIGITE SUA SENHA DE ADMINISTRADOR")));
        if (senhacd == 12345) {
            int codfi = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Digite o código do filme: ")));
            codfi -= 1;
            if (codfi < 0 || codfi > tamanhoDoVetor) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Código inválido");
            } else {
                if (filmeArray[codfi] != null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Código: " + 
                            ((filmeArray[codfi].getCodigo())+1)
                            + "\nTitulo: " + filmeArray[codfi].getTitulo());
                    filmeArray[codfi].setCodigo(0);
                    filmeArray[codfi].setAnodelancamento(0);
                    filmeArray[codfi].setDuracao(0);
                    filmeArray[codfi].setGenero("");
                    filmeArray[codfi].setTitulo("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                            "Exclusão concluida com SUCESSO");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                            "Filme inexistente!");
                }
            }

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "SENHA DO ADMINISTRADOR INVALIDA");
        }
    }
//LOCAÇÕES

    public void alugarFilme() {


        String nomeCliente = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                "Ola, Cliente! \n" + "Digite o seu nome: ");

        for (Cliente d : clienteArray) {
            if (d != null) {
                if (d.getNome().equals(nomeCliente)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigo: "
                            + (d.getCodigo() + 1) + "\nNome: " + d.getNome());

                    String NomeFilme = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                            "Qual filme você procura?");
                    for (Filme c : filmeArray) {

                        if (c != null) {
                            if (c.getTitulo().equals(NomeFilme)) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codigo: "
                                        + (c.getCodigo() + 1) + "\nNome: " + c.getTitulo());
                                String x11 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("escolha a melhor forma de pagamneto ^^ \n 1. Cartão\n2. Boleto\n3. À Vista");
                                switch (x11) {
                                    case "1": {
                                        String cod = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o número do seu cartão");
                                        if (cod.equals("0000000000000000") || cod.equals("1111111111111111") || cod.equals("2222222222222222")
                                                || cod.equals("3333333333333333") || cod.equals("4444444444444444") || cod.equals("5555555555555555")
                                                || cod.equals("6666666666666666") || cod.equals("7777777777777777") || cod.equals("8888888888888888")
                                                || cod.equals("9999999999999999") || (cod.length() != 16)) {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Numero do cartao invalido");
                                        } else {
                                            int nParcelas = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero de parcelas ate 4x: ")));
                                            if (nParcelas >= 1 && nParcelas <= 4) {
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme alugado");
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "o link para você assistir o filme esta desponivel por ate 24hr! ");
                                                Random gerador = new Random();
                                                int RA = (gerador.nextInt(90000));
                                                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "HTTPS://www.locadoraMorenos.com.br/" + d.getNome() + "/" + RA, "HTTPS://www.locadoraMorenos.com.br/" + d.getNome() + "/" + RA);
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Obrigado pela preferencia ^^");
                                            } else {
                                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERRO");

                                            }

                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    case "2": {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme alugado");
                                        Random gerador = new Random();
                                        int RA2 = (gerador.nextInt(90000));
                                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "HTTPS://www.locadoraMorenos.com.br/boletobrasil/" + RA2);

                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Apos o pagamento você recebera um e-mail com o link do filme");
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Obrigado pela preferencia ^^");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    default: {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não trabalhamos com esta forma de pagamento");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Classe: Menu

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Menu {

     ClienteDao dao;
     int opcao;

    private final int CLIENTE = 1;
    private final int ADMIN = 2;
    private final int SAIR = 0;
    private final int CADASTRAR = 1;
    private final int CLI_LISTAR_FILMES = 2;
    private final int CLI_ALUGAR_FILME = 3;

    private final int CONSULTAR_POR_NOME = 2;
    private final int MOSTRAR_TODOS = 3;
    private final int EXCLUIR = 4;
    private final int CADASTRARFILME = 5;
    private final int LISTAR_FILMES = 6;
    private final int REMOVER_FILME = 7;
    private final int ALUGAR_FILME = 8;

    private final String MENU_PRINCIPAL = "Menu de opções\n1 - CLIENTE\n2 - "
            + "ADMINISTRADOR\n0 - SAIR";
    private final String MENU_CLIENTE = "Menu de operaçoes\n1 - Novo "
            + "cadastro\n2 - Mostrar Filmes\n3 - Alugar filme\n0 - Sair ";
    private final String MENU_ADMIN = "Menu de opções\n1 - cria conta de "
            + "cliente\n2 - consultar por nome\n3 - mostrar todos clientes\n4"
            + " - excluir\n5 - adicionar filme\n6  - listar filmes\n7 - "
            + "remover filmes\n8 - alugar filmes\n0 - sair";
    private final String BEMVINDO_CLIENTE = "BEM VINDO A CENTRAL DE "
            + "CADASTRAMENTO DIGITE 1 PARA CONTINUAR";
    private final String BEMVINDO_ADMIN = "BEM VINDO A CENTRAL DE "
            + "CADASTRAMENTO DIGITE 1 PARA CONTINUAR";

    public void menuPrincipal() {
        {

            int qtd = 100;
            dao = new ClienteDao(qtd);

            while (true) {
                opcao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog(MENU_PRINCIPAL));

                switch (opcao) {
                    case CLIENTE: {
                        this.menuCliente();
                        break;
                    }
                    case ADMIN: {
                        this.menuAdministrador();
                        break;
                    }
                    case SAIR: {
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opção inválida");
                    }
                }
                dao.mostrarClientes();
            }
        }
    }

    private void menuCliente() {

        opcao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(MENU_CLIENTE));
        switch (opcao) {
            case CADASTRAR: {
                int qtdcliente = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog(BEMVINDO_CLIENTE, null));
                if (qtdcliente == 1) {
                    dao.cadastroCliente(qtdcliente);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Desculpe mas "
                            + "parece que você não digitou 1");
                }
                break;
            }
            case CLI_LISTAR_FILMES: {
                dao.listaFilmes();
                break;
            }
            case CLI_ALUGAR_FILME: {
                dao.alugarFilme();
                break;
            }
            case SAIR: {
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void menuAdministrador() {
        int senha = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("DIGITE SUA SENHA ADMINISTRADOR: "));
        if (senha == 12345) {
            opcao = Integer
                    .parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(MENU_ADMIN));
            switch (opcao) {
                case CADASTRAR: {
                    int qtdcliente = Integer
                            .parseInt(JOptionPane
                                    .showInputDialog(BEMVINDO_ADMIN, null));
                    if (qtdcliente == 1) {
                        dao.cadastroCliente(qtdcliente);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Desculpe mas parece que você não digitou 1");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case CONSULTAR_POR_NOME: {
                    dao.consultarPorNome();
                    break;
                }
                case MOSTRAR_TODOS: {
                    dao.mostrarClientes();
                    break;
                }
                case EXCLUIR: {
                    dao.apagarCliente();
                    break;
                }
                case CADASTRARFILME: {
                    int qtdfilme = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                            "Digite a quantidade de filme para cadastrar: ",
                            null));
                    dao.cadastrarFilmes(qtdfilme);

                    break;
                }
                case LISTAR_FILMES: {
                    dao.listaFilmes();
                    break;
                }
                case REMOVER_FILME: {
                    dao.removerFilmes();
                    break;
                }
                case ALUGAR_FILME: {
                    dao.alugarFilme();
                    break;
                }
                case SAIR: {
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Classe: Programa (onde contém o método main)

```
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu teste = new Menu();
        teste.menuPrincipal();

    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi. Qual é o erro?

Comment: `if (senha == 12345)` - Ugh...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu problema parece ser esta linha no seu método `menuPrincipal()` da classe `Menu`:

```
dao.mostrarClientes();
```

Ainda mais considerando que isso está dentro de um laço `while (true)`.

---

Entretanto, você sabe para que serve um DAO? Me parece que não, pois o seu DAO não é de fato um DAO. Um DAO deveria ser um objeto cuja **única** finalidade é salvar/persistir/recuperar as informações do seu banco de dados, mesmo que o seu banco de dados seja apenas um array na memória.

Mas o seu DAO faz muito mais do que isso. Ele também lê entrada do usuário e contém regras de negócio. Isso não está certo. O resultado de colocar tantas coisas dentro do DAO é que ele se torna uma gambiarra no formato de uma bola de espaguete sem estrutura reconhecível.

Então fica aqui algumas sugestões:

1. No método `cadastroCliente(int n)` o valor de `n` sempre é 1. Afinal, se o usuário não digitar 1, você não deixa entrar no método. Assim, você pode eliminar este parâmetro e substituir o `aux = n + aux` por `aux++`. E no menu você pode trocar isso:

```java
            int qtdcliente = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog(BEMVINDO_CLIENTE, null));
            if (qtdcliente == 1) {
                dao.cadastroCliente(qtdcliente);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Desculpe mas "
                        + "parece que você não digitou 1");
            }
```

Por isso:

```java
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, BEMVINDO_CLIENTE));
            dao.cadastroCliente();
```

E você também muda a mensagem para tirar o "DIGITE 1 PARA CONTINUAR".

2. Continuando no método `cadastroCliente()`, ao invés de ler o nome do cliente lá dentro, receba-o vindo do lado de fora. Use `cadastroCliente(String nome)`. Você também pode eliminar a variável `aux` simplesmente ao procurar o primeiro espaço vazio no array. Não precisa rastrear de antemão aonde ele está. Se o array estiver lotado, você lança uma exceção. Assim o seu método fica deste jeito:

```java
public void cadastroCliente(String nome) {
    int aux;
    for (aux = 0; aux < clienteArray.length && clienteArray[aux] != null; aux++) {}
    if (aux == clienteArray.length) {
        throw new DAOException("Não há mais espaço para cadastrar clientes");
    }
    Cliente c = new Cliente();
    c.setCodigo(aux);
    c.setNome(nome);
    clienteArray[aux] = c;
}
```

E no seu menu:

```java
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, BEMVINDO_CLIENTE));
            String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome do cliente:");
            try {
                dao.cadastroCliente(nome);
            } catch (DAOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Descuple, ocorreu um erro:\n" + e.getMessage());
            }
```

E você cria uma classe para representar o erro no seu DAO:

```java
public class DAOException extends Exception {
    public DAOException(String message) {
         super(message);
    }

    public DAOException(String message, Throwable cause) {
         super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

3. Você deve fazer algo parecido com os demais métodos do DAO. Receba como parâmetro o que deve ser cadastrado, alterado, consultado ou excluído. No caso da consulta, você deve retornar o que foi consultado. Se o método não puder realizar o seu trabalho por qualquer motivo, lance uma exceção e capture-a na camada acima. **NUNCA** leia dados do usuário ou exiba mensagens para o usuário dentro do seu DAO, pois isso é uma péssima prática de programação. O motivo, é que exibir ou ler dados do usuário foge da responsabilidaade do DAO. Idealmente, se você fosse portar o seu sistema para um ambiente web, você não deveria precisar alterar uma única vírgula no DAO, mas por causa do `JOptionPane` isso não vai acontecer. Então, **não use o `JOptionPane` dentro do DAO**.
4. O seu DAO trabalha com duas entidades: cliente e filme. Recomendo dividi-lo em dois DAOs distintos para evitar de misturar os conceitos.
5. Troque os `System.exit(0); break;` por `return false;` e ao final do método coloque um `return true;`. Faça o método `menuPrincipal` verificar o que foi retornado pelo `menuCliente` e `menuAdministrador` (que será `boolean`) ao invés de sempre ficar repetindo com o `while (true)`. O motivo disso é que ao abortar a execução do programa de súbito, fica difícil realizar quaisquer tarefas pendentes e modificar o programa fica mais complicado. O ideal é deixar que ele termine de forma natural.
6. E isso daqui:

```java
if (senhac2 == 12345)
...
if (senha == 12345)
```

**É HORRÍVEL!** A senha está *hardcoded* no código-fonte e por causa disso não pode ser alterada ou configurada e uma vez roubada o sistema fica comprometido. Acredito que o seu professor não vai gostar nada disso, porque se eu fosse o seu professor, te subtrairia pontos aqui, desculpe-me a franqueza. Ok, mas o que fazer? No mínimo coloque ele em uma variável para não ficar a senha direto no código. O ideal seria criar um DAO de login/senhas ou talvez ler de um arquivo.

7. Isto daqui é bastante frágil:

```java
opcao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog(MENU_PRINCIPAL));
```

O que acontece se ao invés de digitar um número eu digitar o meu nome? O sistema quebra! A solução para issso é tratar a entrada do usuário:

```java
try {
    opcao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog(MENU_PRINCIPAL));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    opcao = -1;
}
```

8. Para evitar de codificar a lógica de negócio dentro do `switch`, encapsule-a em um método. Ou seja, ao invés disso:

```java
            case CADASTRARFILME: {
                int qtdfilme = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        "Digite a quantidade de filme para cadastrar: ",
                        null));
                dao.cadastrarFilmes(qtdfilme);

                break;
            }
```

Use isso:

```java
private void cadastrarFilme() {
    int qtdfilme = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "Digite a quantidade de filme para cadastrar: ",
            null));
    dao.cadastrarFilmes(qtdfilme);
}

// ...

            case CADASTRARFILME: {
                cadastrarFilme();
                break;
            }
```

E com isso, você não precisaria ter que ficar mexendo dentro dos `case`s do `switch` sempre que for alterar uma funcionalidade, pois cada funcionalidade estará isolada dentro de um método.

9. Se você está usando java 7 ou superior, você pode usar `String`s em `switch`es. Com isso fica muito mais fácil digitar algo como "Alugar filme" ao invés de "8". Para facilitar para você, dê um `trim()` e um `toUpperCase()` antes de usar no `switch`.
10. No método `cadastrarFilmes(int qtdfilme)`, você tem isso:

```java
                switch (auxf) {
                    case '1':
                        //                 filmeArray[fi].setGenero("AÇAO");
                        //               filmeArray[fi].setAnodelancamento(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano de Lançamento: ")));
                        //    filmeArray[fi].setDuracao(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duração do filme em minutos: ")));
                        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme: " + filmeArray[fi].getTitulo() + " CADASTRADO!!!");
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        filmeArray[fi].setGenero("COMEDIA");
                        filmeArray[fi].setAnodelancamento(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano de Lançamento: ")));
                        filmeArray[fi].setDuracao(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duração do filme em minutos: ")));
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme: " + filmeArray[fi].getTitulo() + " CADASTRADO!!!");
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        filmeArray[fi].setGenero("SUSPENSE");
                        filmeArray[fi].setAnodelancamento(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano de Lançamento: ")));
                        filmeArray[fi].setDuracao(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duração do filme em minutos: ")));
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme: " + filmeArray[fi].getTitulo() + " CADASTRADO!!!");
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        filmeArray[fi].setGenero("DRAMA");
                        filmeArray[fi].setAnodelancamento(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano de Lançamento: ")));
                        filmeArray[fi].setDuracao(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Duração do filme em minutos: ")));
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Filme: " + filmeArray[fi].getTitulo() + " CADASTRADO!!!");
                        break;
```

Para evitar toda esta repetição de código, sugiro algo assim:

```java
                String generos[] = {"ACAO", "COMEDIA", "SUSPENSE", "DRAMA"};
                int escolhido = auxf - '0';
                if (escolhido <= 0 || escolhido >= generos.length) {
                    throw new DAOException("Gênero inválido.");
                }
                filmeArray[fi].setGenero(generos[escolhido - 1]);
                filmeArray[fi].setAnodelancamento(ano); // ano é um parâmtero do método.
                filmeArray[fi].setDuracao(duracao); // duracao é um parâmetro do método.
```

Você deve combinar esta abordagem com a abordagem usada no `cadastroCliente` para deixar o código limpo.

Por fim, este método não deveria verificar a senha, pois isso não é responsabilidade do DAO. O menu só deve invocar o DAO quando a senha já tiver sido verificada como correta.

11. Encapsule a sua lógica de verificação de cartões de créditos em um método estático. E lembre-se que não é o DAO que tem que se preocupar em fazer isso.
12. Idente o seu código corretamente. Siga as convenções de nomenclatura de variáveis. Dê nomes significativos para as suas variáveis. Use o modificador `private` para campos nas suas classes. Remova importações desnecessárias. Tudo isso ajuda MUITO.

Deve haver mais dezenas de coisas que daria para revisar no seu código. Mas o que está acima já deverá lhe render um bom trabalho para melhorar e corrigir o seu código.

Comment: Victor! Da uma checada no teu email :D Forte abraço.

Answer (score 3):

O problema está na classe `menu`.

Toda vez que entra no `while` ele mostra os clientes  `dao.mostrarClientes();`

Comment: Porque do downvote? Aparentemente a linha `dao.mostrarClientes();` está sobrando no método `menuPrincipal`, e provavelmente está imprimindo coisas a mais!